# jui/datePicker is not clearing or reseting

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2, dropdown

I am using datePicker widget in my yii2 project.
I want to reset it using jQuery. However, when I try to do so it is not reseting the datePicker to it's initial value, but shows 01/01/1970 for null string.

My jquery code is :

```
$('#job-job_type_id').on('change',function(){
    var select1 = $('#jobparent-recurrence_interval').val();
    var select2 = $('#job-client_id').val();
    var select3 = $('#job-job_type_id').val();

    if(select1 != "" && select2 != "" && select3 != "")
    {
        //code when all three selects are selected
        $.ajax({
            url: '/backend/job/old-job-data',
            method: 'get', 
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                recurrence_interval: select1,
                client_name: select2,
                job_type: select3
            }, 
            success:function(response){
                alert('here');
                alert(response.id);

                if(response)
                {

                    $('input:radio[value="'+response.is_billable+'"]').attr('checked', true);

                    $('#job-partner_id').find('option[value='+response.partner_id+']').attr('selected', true);

                    $('#job-team_leader_id').find('option[value='+response.team_leader_id+']').attr('selected', true);

                    $('#job-period_ended').val(response.period_ended);
                    $('#job-target_start_date').val(response.target_start_date);
                    $('#job-target_end_date').val(response.target_end_date);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('in else');
                    $('input:radio[value="'+response.is_billable+'"]').attr('checked', true);




                    $('#job-partner_id option:selected').removeAttr('selected');

                    $('#job-team_leader_id option:selected').removeAttr('selected');



                    $('#job-period_ended').val();                        
                    $.datepicker._clearDate('#job-target_start_date');
                    $('#job-target_end_date').val('');
                }


            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                alert(error);                    
            }
        });
    }
```

Also once my drop-down has been selected, It is not resetting to it's initial value. How can I reset drop-down list?

How can I reset or deselect radio button?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problems

Comment: Use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to change properties like selected and checked. Use datepicker plugin api to change date